# GWT Vs JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, gwt

In my view, JQuery project development is very active these days. The interesting thing which I liked in JQuery is plugins. There are plenty of JQuery plugins freely available on the net. Hence, anyone could easily get nicely created HTML5, CSS3 based JQuery plugins from the net and add it into their web or mobile web application in few mins.

Since I'm a GWT developer, whenever I need a widget, I have to create my custom widget or GXT, smartGWT widget libraries. I'm not seeing any active HTML5, CSS3 based widget projects available in GWT. I think, the only work around would be, add JQuery plugin into GWT application by creating wrapper around it, but, I feel that won't be good idea. What would be the best way to have so many widgets freely available in GWT on net, like we have plugins in JQuery? Is there something already out there?

Comment: GWT and JQuery can be used together. See: http://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/howto-jquery-gwt-integration/

Comment: i've heard of this one in the past, i think it's famous:
http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Comment: GQuery is a jQuery-like API written in GWT, we can not easily translate JQeury plugins into GQuery based widget. Again, we need to rewrite though the syntax looks similar on both.

Comment: Yes, it would become like a creating a wrapper around JQuery plugin, it won't be very efficient though.

Comment: yes i don't see any other solution, because i think this is really the equivalent, you've got gwtqueryui as well

Comment: and i've heard to some conference leaded by Google that user who wanted to seek the the same think that jQuery does should look through this. So i'm pretty sure that you're stuck with only this :/ sorry

Comment: You're right. There so many GWT developers out there and everyone creates their own custom widgets in many situations, if we could share them as UI library to public the way JQuery plugins are shared in the net, that would have been nice to re-use them effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I use JQM4GWT, but that is for the mobile version of JQuery.